# DFF in verilog with a delay

Tags: verilog, flip-flop, nand2tetris, edaplayground

I'm trying to implement the [nand2tetris](http://nand2tetris.org/03.php) project in verilog and am hitting a wall using [icarus verilog](http://iverilog.icarus.com/). In the book they implement the DFF as so, `q(t) = d(t-1)`. The output at the current time is the input at the previous `posedge clk`. Here is the `DFF` I realized.

```verilog
module Dff (
    output reg q,
    input data, clk
);

    reg p;
    reg o;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        o <= data;
        q <= p;
    end

    always @(negedge clk) begin
        p <= o;
    end

endmodule
```

This DFF seems to work just fine when I test it directly. But when I reused it to create a Bit (a memory cell), it gets crazy. Interestingly, the craziness is different using Icarus Verilog or EDAPlayground (which uses VCS).

```verilog
module Mux (out, a, b, sel);
    input a, b;
    input sel;
    output reg out;

    assign out = ~sel ? a : b;
endmodule

module Bit (
    output out,
    input data, load, clk
);

    Mux m0(in, out, data, load);
    Dff d0(out, in, clk);
endmodule
```

### Icarus Verilog output

```
 data | load | clk | out
------+------+-----+-----
    0 |    1 |   1 |   x
    0 |    1 |   0 |   x
    1 |    1 |   1 |   x
    1 |    1 |   0 |   x
    0 |    1 |   1 |   1
    0 |    1 |   0 |   1
    0 |    0 |   1 |   0
    0 |    0 |   0 |   0
    1 |    1 |   1 |   0
    1 |    1 |   0 |   0
    0 |    0 |   1 |   0   # !?!?!
    0 |    0 |   0 |   0   # it should be 1 here.
```

### EDAPlayground output

```
 data | load | clk | out
------+------+-----+-----
    0 |    1 |   1 |   x
    0 |    1 |   0 |   x
    1 |    1 |   1 |   x
    1 |    1 |   0 |   x
    0 |    1 |   1 |   1
    0 |    1 |   0 |   1
    0 |    0 |   1 |   0
    0 |    0 |   0 |   0
    1 |    1 |   1 |   1  # !?!?!
    1 |    1 |   0 |   1  # it should be 0 here.
    0 |    0 |   1 |   1
    0 |    0 |   0 |   1
```

The code is testable on [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/HVX).

Comment: I'd say your DFF is not working correctly, as it uses three D flip-flops when synthesised.

Comment: I dont know if I can properly explain exactly what is happening in both cases but Ill boil it down here: because you are not using non-blocking assignment for your `initial` block (ie `load <= 0`, not `load = 0`, treat it like its coming out of another register somewhere), simulation order of the various blocks in your design (the `always` in the DFF, the `assign` in the Mux and the `always` clocking block and `initial` stimulus block) matters. Ie, when the updates from the `initial` block happen are not happening when you want them to due to the blocking assignment.

Comment: DFF is usually sensitive to one edge of the clock, either posedge or negedge. Why are you using both?

Comment: Your DFF almost looks like a latches. "q(t) = d(t-1)" is simply `always @(posedge clk) begin q <= data; end`. As Unn pointed out, your `data` and `load` stimuli should be non-blocking so it doesn't cause a race condition with the clock. Alternatively, add a little delay so the simultaneous. Point being the new values for the stimuli must be updated after the clock.

Comment: To summarize: my test cases are badly designed hence the code is crap and the behavior hardly predictable. Big TA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Uun and Greg, here is how I fixed the issue. The [code is on EDA playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/DMJ)

A DFF can be simpler.

```verilog
module Dff (
    output reg q,
    input data, clk
);
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        q <= data;
    end
endmodule
```

Then the tests are the culprits. Blocking assignments are causing confusion. A simple way to fix that is to change all the `=` by `<=` like that:

```verilog
module Bit_tb;
    reg clk = 0;
    reg data = 0;
    reg load = 1;
    wire out;

    initial begin
        #2
        data <= 1;

        #2
        load <= 0;  // load = 0; /!\ would be blocking before
        data <= 0;  // data = 0; doing this line. /!\

        #2
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```